# Download dSYMs from Xcode Organizer i get this error "Missing App Record"

Tags: ios, xcode, download, xcode-organizer, dsym

I try to download symbols to debug a crash log  that send me a client (ipa signed with ad hoc distribution), but when I click "Download dSYMs" in Organizer I get this error:

[image: Download dSYMS" generate the error Missing app Record]

Comment: I've the same issue Should we start a bounty ?

Comment: I've to few reputetion points to start a 50 points bounty ):

Comment: @ OXXY 6 is your ipa  distribuited with ad hoc distribution?

Comment: That's right it's ad hoc

Comment: In this case you can found  symbols dSym directly from the xarchive:Right click on the .xcarchive from organizer and select "Show in finder" right click on file and select  'Show Package Contents'  the dSYMs folder is there

Comment: @OXXY did help my suggestion?

Comment: The problem is the file there isn't match the UUID needed (I'm using this for fabric plugin)

Comment: Same issue here. @christianmini: you should either make that workaround a real answer or part of the question, so people will find it more easily. Contrary to tales, answering your own questions will not make you go blind. :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can get symbols dSym directly from the xarchive:

1. Right click on the .xcarchive from organizer
2. Select "Show in finder" right click on file
3. Select 'Show Package Contents' the dSYMs folder is there

As suggested by comments  I've answered to my question.

Comment: Yeah, but if download does not work properly, dsyms contained in .xcarchive give you nothing in terms of fabric debug.

Comment: By nothing I mean that some of the crashes will have <compiler-generated> line 0 message instead of valid stack trace.

Comment: "but if download does not work properly, dsyms contained in .xcarchive give you nothing in terms of fabric debug"

@b.zdybowicz  Hi did you figure out this issue?